# How can I join two lines in a file if they both fit a pattern?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with multiple lines and I want to join lines if they both fit a specific pattern.

I know that I can find lines that fit the pattern and get the next line with:

```
grep -E -A1 'Pattern' filename
```

But how can I check if the next line also fits the pattern and how would I go about joining the two?

For example,
I have a file like this:

```
Hello
i
am
John
Smith
```

An example pattern could be the following:

```
'^[A-Z][a-z]+'
```

So in this case, I would like to combine the rows, if they both start with capital letters.

The output I would like to achieve would be:

```
Hello
i
am 
John Smith
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]+/{
  :a
  N
  /\n[A-Z][a-z]+/{
    s/\n/ /
    b a
  }
}
```

Save it as `join.sed` and to execute: `sed -Ef join.sed file`.

If the line matches the pattern, we start a loop that appends the next line
to pattern space and replaces the newline character with a space as long as
that line also matches the pattern.

For GNU Sed you can collapse it to an one-liner:

```
sed -E '/^[A-Z][a-z]+/{:a;N;/\n[A-Z][a-z]+/{s/\n/ /;b a}}' file
```

---

Alternatively, an Awk script, `join.awk`, for which the pattern should be given as `p`:

```
{
    if($0~p)c+=1
    else c=0
    printf "%s%s", (c>1 ? " " : ors), $0
    ors=ORS
}
END{print ""}
```

To execute: `awk -f join.awk p='^[A-Z][a-z]+' file`.

Answer (score 2):

Usin `sed` with null character as separator (`-z`):

```bsh
$ sed -z 's/\([A-Z][a-z]\+\)\n\([A-Z][a-z]\+\)/\1 \2/'
Hello
i
am
John Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -e 'given lines.join("\n") { S/ $<first>=[<upper><lower>+] \n $<last>=[<upper><lower>+] /$<first> $<last>/.put};'
```

Sample Input:

```
Hello
i
am
John
Smith
goodbye
```

Sample Output:

```
Hello
i
am
John Smith
goodbye
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of languages. Data is `given` to Raku in the form of `lines`, but as Raku's `lines` routine auto-chomps input, the data is `join`-ed with newlines. While this may seem a little convoluted, the advantage is  Raku's `lines` routine reads data lazily, meaning the code above *should be* memory-efficient.

Raku implements a `S///` "non-destructive" operator, which is similar (if not identical to) the familiar `s///` operator (Raku has that one, too). The capital-`S` operator has one advantage in that it *"leaves the original string intact and returns the resultant string instead of $/ (the match variable)."*

Within the matching (left) half of the `S///` operator, ***named captures*** are employed. The regex engine first searches for `[<upper><lower>+]` and assigns it to named capture `$<first>`, it then searches for a `\n` (newline), and finally it searches for another `[<upper><lower>+]`, this time assigning it to the named capture `$<last>`. To finish, within the substitution (right) half of the `S///` operator, the two named captures `$<first> $<last>` are used to replace the left-hand side match, although *with* a space and *without* the `\n` newline in between.

An alternative way of accomplishing the same thing is below. The code omits named captures, instead using `<(\n)>` to drop everything from the match object except what is inside the `<(…)>` capture markers. Then in the replacement, `\n`  is replaced with   space:

```perl
raku -e 'put S/ [<upper><lower>+] <(\n)> [<upper><lower>+] / / given lines.join("\n");'
```

*[Note, the code above will only collapsed something like `George\nHerbert\nWalker\nBush` from 4 lines into 3 (`George Herbert\nWalker\nBush`). If you want all linewise consecutive occurences of `[<upper><lower>+]` returned on one line, please feel free to post that Question].*

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#S///_non-destructive_substitution
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex__Named_captures-Named_captures
https://raku.org